# Angular http post promise not working but ajax is

Tags: ajax, angular

I'm trying to make a post using the following code but I get this error:

short-form.component.ts

```
this.shortFormService.update(formModel)
  .then(res => {        
      this.router.navigate(['/goHere'])
    }
  );
```

short-form.service

```
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;'});

 update(formModel): Promise<ShortFormModel> {
  return this.http
   .post(this.preCheckUrl, JSON.stringify(formModel), {headers: this.headers})
   .toPromise()
   .then(res => {
   res.json().data as ShortFormModel;       
  })
  .catch(
    (error: any): Promise<any>=> {         
      this.router.navigate(['/error', error]);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
  )
```

}

```
Error: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:8080/endpoint
```

However, If I just ajax it works:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint',
  data: JSON.stringify(formModel),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("success");
  },
  error: function (response) {
    console.log("failed");
  }
});
```

Any ideas on what is happening here? I've looked at other posts and content-type seems to be an issue with other. However, I am setting (maybe incorrectly)  'Content-Type': 'application/json;' with new Headers(). Or, is this an issue with how promise is set up?

Comment: Try adding : let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers }); and use "options" in your POST call instead of "{headers: this.headers}". Maybe it could change something

Comment: No luck, same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;'});

 update(formModel): Promise<ShortFormModel> {
  let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = this.headers;
  return this.http
   .post(this.preCheckUrl, JSON.stringify(formModel), options)
   .toPromise()
   .then(res => {
   res.json().data as ShortFormModel;       
  })
  .catch(
    (error: any): Promise<any>=> {         
      this.router.navigate(['/error', error]);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
  )
```

The `Headers` need to be added as part of the `RequestOptions` directive.

Comment: I normally make a private method that retun a `RequestOptions` array which add default headers automatically and all you have to do is call the method. I can give a sample of that if you need to go down that route

Answer (score 0):

I feel very silly but the root cause was because I did not disable

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
```

that I was using for dev before services were ready.

The solution I went with is pretty much out of angular's tutorial:

short-form.component

```
onSubmit(shortForm: any) {
 if (!shortForm) { return; }
 const formModel = this.shortForm.value;

this.shortFormService.create(formModel)
  .subscribe(res => {
          this.router.navigate(['/apply'])
        })       
}
```

short-form.service

```
create(shortForm: any): Observable<ShortFormModel> {
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this.http.post(this.preCheckUrl, shortForm, options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```